# What is the highest muzzle velocity of a gun on any fighter aircraft?

Tags: fighter

I'm looking for the greatest muzzle velocity of a gun on any fighter aircraft.

I looked up the GAU-8 Avenger from the A10 Warthog first. Its muzzle velocity is 1,070 m/s, which is pretty darn high (almost 3 times the speed of sound). Are there any faster bullets out there from an aircraft gun?

Note: Don't really care about the firing rate (rounds per minute), or bullet caliber. All I'm looking for is highest muzzle velocity.

Comment: BK 37 apparently had 1170 m/s muzzle velocity with APCR ammunition. Hans Ulrich Rudel who was a consultant for A10 used fly a Stuka equipped with one. So it seems a legit case of "weapon with similar power to GAU-8". Although rate of fire was much lower.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The muzzle velocity of guns is based on multiple factors and generally sees a wide range. Most importantly how the bullet is loaded (gun powder wise) and what mass the bullet is. For example the P-51 mustang carried 6 [50 caliber BMG's (M-2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M2_Browning). Which (although not available at the time) is capable of accepting the [Caliber .50, Saboted Light Armor Penetrator, M903](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.50_BMG#Military_cartridge_types) round which has a quoted muzzle velocity of 4,000 ft/s (1,219 m/s). It should also be noted that the base muzzle velocity of an M2 is 2,910 ft/s (890 m/s) for [M33 ball round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.50_BMG#Military_cartridge_types). So it really depends what round you are loading in.

The [F-35 Joint Strike Fighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-35_Lightning_II) has the [GAU-22 Gatling Gun](http://www.gd-ots.com/armament_systems/mbw_GAU-22A.html) which with the TP HEI ammunition has a quoted muzzle velocity of 3,560 feet (1,085m) per second (15 m/s faster than the GAU-8 on the warthog). 
[image]

(Not sure about you guys but I often test my gatling guns with my multi-meter...)
[image source](http://www.militaryparitet.com/perevodnie/data/ic_perevodnie/2105)

Comment: Technically the P-51 carried 4 or 6 M2 .50s, not 2 :)

Comment: Dave, can you provide a source for the image? (Image Attribution)

Comment: Edits made, thanks guys.

Comment: Fine answer ... except the image, which seems to be decorative at best.

Comment: that is an image of the GAU-22 the gun (and F-35) in question, granted a bit humorous it is still on topic.

Comment: The guy with the multi-meter is in the GD brochure: http://www.gd-ots.com/armament_systems/GAU-22-A.pdf

Comment: Why is the plane's engine seemingly not running? (Obviously the guns and multimeter guy are photoshopped in; was the plane added as well?